# Javascript won't recognise json element as number

Tags: javascript, undefined

I'm processing a json object and want to display a number with two decimal places, but javascript says the type is 'undefined'.

I've tried using .toFixed(2), Number() and ParseFloat() to force it to be a number, and I've even tried String() to force it to change to a string, but it stubbornly remains as 'undefined'. typeof isn't even recognised as a property of the original element.

Surely there's a way to convert it / properly define it. I'd appreciate help and an explanation of why what I'm doing doesn't work.

```js
data = {
  list: {
    9: {
      balance: 256.3999999999942
    }
  },
  action: 'load',
  status: 'ACCTLOADED'
}

showAccounts(data);

function showAccounts(data) {
  action = data.action;
  status = data.status;
  accs = data.list;

  if ((action == 'load') && (status == 'ACCTLOADED')) { // data retrieved
    $.each(accs, function(acc, details) { // display each account
      let bal = 0;
      bal = Number(details.balance);
      console.log('bal ' + bal + bal.typeof);
    });
  }
} // end function showAccounts
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's not JSON, that's just a JavaScript object. What's not clear here is why `$.each` is being used.

Comment: `typeof bal` instead of `bal.typeof`

Comment: That `data` initializer is also a syntax error. *edit* oh wait no it isn't, I must have slept through that one.

Comment: It's a javascript representation of a JSON object that demonstrates the same problem. I use $.each to iterate through the list of accounts. I only included one because it was sufficient for the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think bal is already type of number.
Use like:

```
console.log('bal ' + bal + typeof bal);
```

Comment: Facepalm. Thanks. It looks like I fixed the problem somewhere along the way, but couldn't see it because I was using 'typeof' incorrectly.